# Proving that the absolute value of x is greater then or equal to $0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, real-numbers

My Question reads:

Prove for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $|x|\geq\ 0$.

This is for a set theory class where we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of Dedekind cuts.

For each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we define

$|x|$ = max{$x, −x$}
 = $x ∪ (−x)$

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we define

$−x$ = {$r\in\mathbb{Q} | (∃s > r) − s\notin\ x$}.

We define the binary relation $<_\mathbb{R}$ on R by

$x <_\mathbb{R} y$ iff $x\subset\ y$.

I am not too sure where to start for this. Should we consider subsets instead? Is this saying that $0$ is a subset of $|x|$?

A Dedekind Cut is a subset $x\subset\mathbb{Q}$ such that:

$\emptyset\neq\ x\neq\mathbb{Q}$

$x$ is downwards closed, i.e. if $q\in\ x$ and $r<q$, then $r\in\ x$

$x$ has no largest element.

Also, $0$ = {$r\in\mathbb{Q} | r < 0$}

Comment: How do you define $|x|$ for a Dedekind cut $x$?

Comment: What is your definition of $|x|$?  What do you know about $\geq$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I have made the changes.

Comment: @EclipseSun I have added the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, we are to show that either $0\subseteq x$ or $0\subseteq -x$.

Suppose that $0\subseteq x$ does not hold. This means there exists some $s\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $s\notin x$ but $s\in 0$ (i.e. $s<0$).
[Remark: This depends on your definition of Dedekind cut. $s\in 0$ may stand for $s\le 0$ if the other convention is used.]

In this case, for any $r\in 0$, i.e. $r<0$ [or $r\le 0$], we have $-s>r$. By definition of $-x$, we see that $r\in -x$, since $-(-s)=s\notin x$. Hence $0\subseteq -x$.

Therefore, $|x|\ge 0$.

Comment: Why would assuming $0\subseteq x$ give us that $s\notin x$? Also, how do we know $s< 0$? Also, yes, we use either convention.

Comment: If $0\subseteq x$, then we are done. So I suppose $0\not\subseteq  x$ and then prove that $0\subseteq -x$.

Comment: Oh wait, if we have one then done, but if we don't have that one, we need to prove the other.

Comment: I think I am just more confused by what follows after this. Wouldn't it be that $-s\notin x$?

Comment: $A\not\subseteq B$ means $\exists x\in A$ and $x\notin B$.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using the definition of $0$.

Comment: So, once we have that $s\in\ 0$, we take another value $r$ which we know if $<0$ by definition of $0$. Then, how did you get $-s>r$?

Comment: Because $-s$ is a positive rational while $r$ is a negative rational.

Comment: Can we not just have $s>r$ by the fact of  downwards closed?

Comment: Why do you need $s>r$? In general this does not hold.

Comment: I think I just do not understand why you introduce this $r\in\ 0$. Can we not instead say that since $s<0$ and $s\geq\ x$, then $x < 0$?

Comment: But we need to show that $0< -x$. Although $x<0$ implies $0<-x$, I don't know if this is a lemma that you've already proved.

Comment: Yes, since we are doing subsets then, don't we need to prove something in $0$ is also in $-x$?

Comment: Well, can't we just take the negative of $x<0$?

Comment: That's why I introduce $r$. Of course you can take the negative of $x<0$, once you prove the lemma that $a<b$ implies $-b<-a$ for any Dedekind cuts $a,b$.